# Clarification Needed on Tarjan's Algorithm Implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I've been working on the Tarjan's algorithm for finding critical connections in a network, specifically applied to the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/critical-connections-in-a-network) outlined in this LeetCode challenge.

Here is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    timer=0
    def criticalConnections(self, n: int, connections: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        graph=defaultdict(list)
        for a,b in connections:
            graph[a].append(b)
            graph[b].append(a)

        result=[]
        tin=[0]*n
        low=[0]*n
        visited=[False]*n
        def dfs(node,parent):
            self.timer+=1
            visited[node]=True
            tin[node]=self.timer
            low[node]=self.timer
            for child in graph[node]:
                if child==parent: continue
                if visited[child]:
                    low[node]=min(low[node],tin[child])
                else:
                    dfs(child,node)
                    low[node]=min(low[node],low[child])
                    if tin[node]<low[child]:
                        result.append([node,child])
        dfs(0,-1)
        return result
```

Why can't we use the condition `if low[node]<low[child]:` instead of `if tin[node]<low[child]:` to decided whether a bridge exists or not?

I understand that if the low of my child is bigger than my low, then it means that it can never be reached before me, hence indicating a bridge.

Comment: Interesting question, but it seems like it's off topic here, since you are analyzing the algorithm as opposed to trying to fix the implementation; cs.stackexchange.com seems like a more appropriate forum.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for the info. Btw, I found the answer for this problem and have put in the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78037809/6821016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who will stumble on this doubt in future. `if low[node]<low[child]:` would fail for this undirected graph
`[[0,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,3],[1,3]]`
[image]